# Select columns from DataFrame if first row is 0

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select all columns of a dataframe(df) into a new dataframe where the value of the first row is ==0.

df=

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  0  3  0
1  2  7  2  2
2  3  5  2  1
```

new_df:

```
     b   d
0    0   0
1    7   2
2    5   1
```

It feels like a simple task but I am completly stuck in finding something that works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use first [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `:` for select all rows and columns by condition - compare first row:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.iloc[0] == 0]
```

Or compare row with `label=0`, obviously first too:

```
df1 = df.loc[:, df.loc[0].eq(0)]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   b  d
0  0  0
1  7  2
2  5  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Or try `loc` with `iloc`:

```
>>> df.loc[:, df.iloc[0].eq(0)]
   b  d
0  0  0
1  7  2
2  5  1
>>>
```

This will select the columns where the first row is 0.

Or try with `T`:

```
>>> df.T[df.T.eq(0).any(1)].T
   b  d
0  0  0
1  7  2
2  5  1
>>>
```